# Sending objects to localhost server using java?

Tags: java, file, object, serialization

How do I create a .ser file or write objects to a .ser file in a localhost server?

The following code can read .ser file :

```
   public Object deserialize(InputStream is) {
    ObjectInputStream in;
    Object obj;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        obj = in.readObject();
        in.close();
        return obj;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    }


        URL url;
        URLConnection urlConn;
        DataInputStream dis;

        //url = new URL("http://localhost/Person.ser");

        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        Person person = (person) deserialize(urlConn.getInputStream());
```

Do I need any server side program to receive the object and store in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write to .ser file using following way:

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Filename.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.write(obj);
        fos.close();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {}
```

**UPDATE**
To read the object at server side you need to create `ObjectInputStream` wrappint the inputStream of socket via which it is interacting with client . It can be done as follows:

```
try
      {
        Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        Object obj = oin.readObject();
        oin.close();
      }catch(Exception ex){}
```

OK here is the complete example where I am sending an ArrayList to Server.
**Client.java**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Socket s = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;  
        System.out.println("Connecting to Server ...");
        try 
        {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 1401);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream (s.getOutputStream());
            ArrayList<String> list = ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        list.add("String"+i);
    }
            out.writeObject(list);out.flush();
        System.out.println("ArrayList sent to Server");
        } catch ( Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (out!= null)
            {
                try
                {
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
            if (s != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    s.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server.java**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ObjectInputStream oin = null;
        ServerSocket server;
        Socket socket = null;
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(1401);
            socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client Connected..Sending ArrayList to Client");
            oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>)oin.readObject();
        System.out.println("Recieved ArrayList from client "+list);
            //Writing to file now 
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Filename.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.write(obj);
            fos.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Written to file");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (oin != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    oin.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
            if (socket != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    socket.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I want to write to a file in a remote server and not on my computer.

Comment: @AntonioKumar Then first you would have to send that object to the remove server via socket and then write it over there using the above given code.

Comment: I still don't get it. How do i send it? Can you give me some examples or references?

Comment: Thanks I got it. But suppose now I want to write it to a remote server using either ftp oe sftp and not to localhost. So in server.java new ServerSocket(1401) won't work. What change do I need to make.

Comment: I suppose also in the client side, i need to add username and password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26812/discussion-between-antonio-kumar-and-vishal-k)